# Stored Procedure containing a cursor taking long time to execute

Tags: sql-server, database-cursor

I have a stored procedure that creates a dynamic view based on the available databases. These databases will be stored in a table say cloud_database_list. I am reading those with the cursor and a string is formed based on the cursor to generate a view.

The problem is if there are more than 200 databases in the list, then it takes about 10 - 11 minutes to run. The procedure is called from a VB application where the command timeout is 60 seconds. I need to run the procedure within 60 seconds.

Am I deviating from any best practice related with performance? Any help would be much appreciated.

Tried with `LOCAL READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY` option for the cursor but no use. I could not use the select / set operation as SELECT @sql += name from cloud_database_list as I need to read a value from every database that is read from the cloud_database_list table.

```
CREATE or alter PROCEDURE create_cloud_views
AS 
DECLARE @db_name nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @year varchar(20)
DECLARE @cmpcode int
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
DECLARE @str as nvarchar(400)
DECLARE @from_date as date
DECLARE @to_date as date
BEGIN TRY
    set @sql = ''
    DECLARE db_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT [DB_NAME] from basedb..cloud_database_list cdl
    INNER JOIN sys.databases d on d.[name] = cdl.[db_name] where cdl.type = 'MY_COND'
    OPEN db_cur
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cur into @db_name
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @year = right(@db_name,(4))
        SET @cmpcode = substring(@db_name,(8),len(@db_name)-(13))
        SET @str = 'select @from_date = fromdate, @to_date = todate  from ' + @db_name + '..mastertable where code = ''C' + cast(@cmpcode as varchar) + ''''
        EXEC sp_executesql @str, N'@from_date datetime Output,@to_date datetime Output', @from_date output, @to_date Output 
        IF @sql = ''
            set @sql = 'CREATE VIEW view_audit_summary AS '
        ELSE
            set @sql = @sql + ' UNION ALL '
        set @sql = @sql + char(10)
        SET @sql = @sql + '(SELECT ''' + cast(@cmpcode as varchar) + ''' as id, ''' + @year + ''' as year, A.IDATE as tran_date, sum(a.tran_cnt) as transaction_count  FROM ' + char(10)
        SET @sql = @sql + '(SELECT COUNT(SEQNO) tran_cnt, convert(varchar(10),IDATE,120) IDATE FROM ' + @db_name + '..TBL1 GROUP BY IDATE ' + char(13)
        SET @sql = @sql + 'UNION ALL ' + char(10)
        SET @sql = @sql + 'SELECT COUNT(SEQNO) tran_cnt, convert(varchar(10),InvDate,120) IDATE FROM ' + @db_name + '..TBL2 where InvDate >= ''' +cast(@from_date as varchar) + ''' and InvDate <= ''' + cast(@to_date as varchar) + ''' GROUP BY InvDate) a'
        SET @sql = @sql + ' group by a.IDATE)' + char(10)
        print @db_name
        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cur into @db_name    
    END
    exec('if exists (select name from sys.views where name = ''view_audit_summary'') drop view view_audit_summary')
    exec(@sql)
    CLOSE db_cur
    DEALLOCATE db_cur
    set @sql = ''

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF CURSOR_STATUS('GLOBAL','db_cur') >= 1
    BEGIN
        CLOSE db_cur
        DEALLOCATE db_cur
    END
    --print cast(error_message() as varchar(100))
END CATCH
```

Comment: 10-11 minutes isn't really that long, in my opinion. You do, however, really need to quote your objects and declare your lengths  and **not** inject values into your statement that should be parametrised. You'll probably be better off using `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML PATH` to create the entire statement though, rather than using a `CURSOR`. Here's a "few" tips: [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: I wouldn't use a cursor here. Instead leverage sys.databases to build your dynamic sql and then execute it. Would be faster by an order of magnitudes. But it would take some time to decipher this dynamic sql to fully grasp what it is doing since there isn't any details about the tables here.

Comment: Oh god... it's a dynamic dynamic statement (`@str` is used to get dynamic values for each iteration). Yes, this can be improved, but it is *not* going to be a quick fix; and (sorry) not something I'd really be willing to do for free.

Comment: Dear @Larnu hope quoting objects will not make much impact. I need to get the result in under 1 min.

Comment: It won't make an impact on performance, no @Keerthivel, it will stop injection though, which is a huge problem. Gtting rid of the `CURSOR` will fix the performance, but you'll need a huge rewrite for that.

Comment: Some errors: `@cmpcode` is declared as INT, but assigned a `substring()` result, also `@tran_year` is undeclared or should that be `@year`?

Comment: Have to as, as well; how many years do you know which are made up of 20 digits? Even the dinosaurs were only around 200,000,000-65,000,000 years ago (which is only 9 digits).

Comment: Thank you @Larnu. Will try the temp table approach and update you.

Comment: This is why data warehouses exist. If you don't need current information, you could always cache the results of the select in the loop to your local database and have a job that runs that as often as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Running a cursor over 200 rows is *NOT* causing your performance issue.  That takes milliseconds.

The only thing that could reasonably be causing a long run time for this procedure is calling this for every database:

```
    SET @tran_year = right(@db_name,(4))
    SET @cmpcode = substring(@db_name,(8),len(@db_name)-(13))
    SET @str = 'select @from_date = fromdate, @to_date = todate  from ' + @db_name + '..mastertable where code = ''C' + cast(@cmpcode as varchar) + ''''
    EXEC sp_executesql @str, N'@from_date datetime Output,@to_date datetime Output', @from_date output, @to_date Output
```

or, at the end dropping the existing view.

```
exec('if exists (select name from sys.views where name = ''view_audit_summary'') drop view view_audit_summary')
```

These both appear to relatively cheap, but either one could be become blocked by concurrent transactions.

Comment: +1 Thanks @David Browne. After every loop I tried printing the database name and every batch takes 1-2 seconds to execute which is acceptable. But considering that there are 200 batches it is taking around 400 seconds i.e 7 mins almost. Any operation that would generate these with a better complexity rather than that of the cursor loop would be helpful.

Comment: Why is the query in the loop taking 1-2 seconds?

Comment: May be due to the operations done as you mentioned. Also, there are no concurrent transactions running.

Comment: Then isolate the query that's taking 1-2 seconds and troubleshoot it.

Comment: Yeah. Will update you by tomorrow morning. It's midnight here. Thanks for the immediate response.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things jump out at me:

```
exec('if exists (select name from sys.views where name = ''view_audit_summary'') drop view view_audit_summary')
```

if you are sql server 2016 or above, you could use `DROP VIEW IF EXISTS ...`  It won't likely perform better but it will read better.

```
exec(@sql)
```

how long does the executed statement get?  Maybe you could write the values to a temp table and just select from the temp table when the loop is done?

Comment: The forming of the @sql takes around 9 mins and then it gets executed within 2 mins

Comment: Yeah, I'd save the results to a temp table as I go, instead of building up a big dyn sql